# Valuation associated to a non-zero prime ideal of the ring of integers

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I have a question from Frohlich & Taylor's book 'Algebraic Number Theory', p.64. I will keep the notation used there.

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal o$ its ring of integers. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a non-zero prime ideal of $\mathcal o$ and $v=v_\mathfrak p$ the valuation of $K$ associated to $\mathfrak p$. Suppose that $\rho$ is a field automorphism of $K$ such that $v(x^\rho)=v(x)$ for all $x\in K$.

> Why is this equivalent to the condition $\mathfrak p^\rho=\mathfrak p$?

Would it help to show that $(x\mathfrak o)^\rho=x^\rho\mathfrak o$ for all $x\in K$? - although I am not sure if this is even true.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: The function $f(x) = \nu(x^\rho)$ is a valuation on $K$. If $f = \nu$ then the conditions $f(x) > 0$ and $\nu(x) > 0$ mean the same thing. We have $\mathfrak p = \{x \in K : \nu(x) > 0\} \cup \{0\}$. Figure out what the solutions of $f(x) > 0$ look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v(x)$ is the number $n$ such that $x \in \mathfrak{p}^n-\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}$ now $v(x)\geq 1$ iff $x \in \mathfrak{p}$.

So we see that if $v(x^{\rho})=v(x)$ then 
$$x^{\rho} \in \mathfrak{p} \Leftrightarrow x \in \mathfrak{p}$$
which means that $\mathfrak{p}^{\rho}=\mathfrak{p}$.

Conversely if $\mathfrak{p}^{\rho}=\mathfrak{p}$ then it is easy to see
$$x^{\rho} \in \mathfrak{p}^n-\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}\Leftrightarrow x \in \mathfrak{p}^n-\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}$$

and so $v(x^{\rho})=v(x)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your clear answer. Regards